# Facebook App open in html webpage

Tags: android, ios, facebook, html

I have a web app with a button to "share this post on facebook". I would like that it could open the facebook app (from iOs or Android) instead of the facebook web page.

Does anyone knows if it is possible?

http://zam.ba/demo

Answer (score 0):

Use the Facebook SDKs (for iOS and Android respectively). They both contain mechanisms that allow your app to share via the FB app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share